# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-layout

This error comes only when I run my application on an Android 4.4.2, not when I run it on Android 5 or above.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
   
    <TextView android:text="Hello World!" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gmail.saadbnwhd.mybudget" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/budget"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        android:largeHeap="true"
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <provider
                    android:name=".data.NoteContentProvider"
                    android:authorities="com.okason.simplenotesapp.data.provider"
                    android:exported="false"
                    android:multiprocess="true" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Addition" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

App.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gmail.saadbnwhd.mybudget"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
   // compile 'com.mobilesiri.sqliteexample'
}
```

LogCat:

```
09-20 11:52:12.576 24023-24023/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-20 11:52:12.756 24023-24023/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-20 11:52:12.756 24023-24023/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-20 11:52:12.848 24023-24033/? E/jdwp: jdwp::setsockopt(SO_SNDTIMEO)
09-20 11:52:12.848 24023-24033/? E/jdwp: jdwp::setsockopt(SO_RCVTIMEO)
09-20 11:52:13.373 24038-24038/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-20 11:52:13.540 24038-24038/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-20 11:52:13.540 24038-24038/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-20 11:52:13.637 24038-24044/? E/jdwp: jdwp::setsockopt(SO_SNDTIMEO)
09-20 11:52:13.637 24038-24044/? E/jdwp: jdwp::setsockopt(SO_RCVTIMEO)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate: Exception while inflating <vector>
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:541)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:478)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:441)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:736)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:359)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:189)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:182)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:717)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:187)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at com.gmail.saadbnwhd.mybudget.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
09-20 11:52:13.751 24048-24048/? E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.gmail.saadbnwhd.mybudget, PID: 24048
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gmail.saadbnwhd.mybudget/com.gmail.saadbnwhd.mybudget.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02004f
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02004f
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2152)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:710)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:346)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:194)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:182)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:717)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:187)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.gmail.saadbnwhd.mybudget.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2148)
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:710) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:346) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:194) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:182) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:717) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:187) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.gmail.saadbnwhd.mybudget.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
09-20 11:52:13.763 24048-24048/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Toolbar is an UI element which is natively available for Android 5.0 and above. Use **Android design support Library** to use it below Android 5.0.

Comment: @SripadRaj I got the library from SDK Manager. It showed Rev 38. Now do I need to also add it in Gradle's dependencies?

Comment: @DivisinSi there's no mention of `Toolbar` in the LogCat. However it says something about your `abc_vector_test.xml`. Could you share that too?

Comment: It's solved. I had to upgrade my gradle plugin version. The problem was with the AssetTag thingy:  invalid drawable tag vector.
Had to add two lines in gradle for that.
Thanks though.
And sorry for not being very clear in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved. I had to upgrade my gradle plugin version using:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

The problem was with the AssetTag thingy which was causing `invalid drawable tag vector`.

Had to add two lines in gradle for that.

This is what the app.gradle's edited portion looked like then.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.gmail.saadbnwhd.sfas"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    generatedDensities = []  //Added line 1st
}

//Added lines 2nd
aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
}
```

Plus, I had to update my Android SDK, and get its 'Android Support Library' from SDK Manager.

Comment: While at it consider updating to build tools 24.0.2.